# Trying to assign Javascript array variable to HTML input value attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input

I have something of a complicated question to ask, and my Google-Fu is apparently too weak to solve this so far.

I'm building a form of sorts that's supposed to flip through a bunch of names in an array, present them all for selection, and:

- Put the selected name into one set of form inputs (text, specifically);
- Dynamically generate a bunch of divs with more of the same text inputs;
- Put the *rest* of the names into those new divs

I've gotten the first two of these to work just fine, with a mix of JQuery and regular Javascript. But the problem I have occurs at the last step, there.

Here's a sample line for what I'm doing:

```
var lname = '<p>Last name: <input type=\'text\' class=\'inputbox\' value=lastNames[i] /></p>';
...
...
$('.others').append(...,lname,...);
```

This is inside a `for (i=0; i<lastNames.length; i++)` loop, so the plan is to create a div and the inputs inside for each name in the array. This already works. The problem is that when I load the page and select a name, 3 new divs show up...and the text inside each box is, for example, lastNames[i] instead of Smith.

What am I missing syntactically here? Or is it more complex than I was thinking?

Answer (score 0):

Right now all you are doing is setting a string. You need to concat the lastNames variable to the string to get your desired results.

```
var lname = '<p>Last name: <input type=\'text\' class=\'inputbox\' value=\'' + lastNames[i] + '\'></p>';
```

Comment: That was it. I could have sworn I tried that already to no avail, but clearly I hadn't. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you looking in [jQuery templating](http://api.jquery.com/category/plugins/templates/) this solution is very suitable for your problem.

**EDIT:** Basically you just set a ready template and then input {{each}} conditional format and it will automatically create the list you have, without any for loops in js.

Comment: It's a neat idea, but I don't think it'll work for our environment (I neglected to mention this all has to run in a browser inside another program, so I'm not sure how far the "compatibility" extends). Thanks, though; I'll probably use this for other projects in the future, as long as the templating team doesn't take down the documentation.

Comment: @KarlM for example standart c# browser tool uses IE as browser. You just need to check witch browser engine is used.